How to hide a row in table when updating the same row ASP.NET Core MVC
I have a view that has multiple renders (Equipment, PA, Seizures), each render is a table with information pulled from my SQL Server DB. I have an update and delete button, when I click on the update button for a row, I want the row to stay in the table, but it adds an editable row to the table and doesn't hide the row I want to edit. All the tables are on the same page and I have different names for the ids.
Seizure view:
<div style="background-color:lightgray; width:25%" class="full-width">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:75%; background-color:white" cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                            <th><!--Edit--></th>
                            <th><!--Delete--></th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Rqkey"/>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Szkey"/>
                   
                        @{
                            if(Model.Seizures != null)
                            {
                                int rownum = 0;
                                foreach (Seizure sez in Model.Seizures)
                                {
                                    <tr id="@rownum">
                                        <td><!--#--></td>
                                        <td>@sez.Category</td>
                                        <td>@sez.Item</td>
                                        <td>@sez.Qty</td>
                                        <td>@sez.Value</td>
                                        <td><input type="button" value="Update" onclick="showSeizure(@sez.Szkey); hides(@rownum)" /></td>
                                        <td><a asp-action="DeleteSeizure" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove @sez.Item?')" asp-route-id="@sez.Szkey">Delete</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr style="display:none" id="@sez.Szkey">
                                        <td>
                                            @{
                                                @await Html.PartialAsync("UpdateSeizure", sez)
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    rownum++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                </tbody>
                
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" id="@Model.Rqkey">
        <td>
            @{
                @await Html.PartialAsync("CreateSeizure", Model)
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Create Record" onclick="showCreate(@Model.Rqkey)" />
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showSeizure(keys){
        document.getElementById(keys).style.display = "contents";
    }

    function hides(rownums){
        document.getElementById(rownums).style.display = "none";
    }

    function showCreate(rqKey) {
        // Fetch the CreateSeizure partial content using AJAX
        fetch('@Url.Action("CreateSeizure")?rqKey=' + rqKey)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                // Insert the fetched partial view into the modal body
                document.getElementById('modal-body-content').innerHTML = data;
                // Show the modal
                $('#createModal').modal('show');
            });
    }
</script>

Here's what it looks like:

Here's how i want it to look:


Do you specifically mean that the one line of code in the hides function isn't doing what you expect?  Or something else?  If the entire problem is with client-side code then can you update this to a [mcve] of the resulting HTML/CSS/JavaScript as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

Yes, I expect the hides function in the seizure view to do the same thing as it does in the Equipment view but currently if I click on the update button inside the seizure table it will add a row that is editable and keep the column that I want to hide.

That function does only one thing, it updates the display style to "none" for a specific element on the page.  If that's the operation you're referring to, what is the value of rownums being used when the problem occurs and what element on the page is it targeting?  For help debugging this, please update the question to a [mcve] which can be independently tested to demonstrate the problem.  Currently you're showing a lot of server-side code but describing a client-side problem.

As a guess... You're doing this in both tables: <tr id="@rownum">  Are both of these tables on the same page?  And are any of those rownum values duplicated?  The id values need to be unique throughout the page.  (Otherwise, when referencing an element by its id, which element would you be referencing?)

Yes both tables are on the same page. I tried changing the id value but it still did the same thing. i changed it from  , <tr id=@rownums">. I'll tried changing it to something completely different for all the tables and still got the same result

What is the difference between numrow and rownums?  What actual values are being used for the id attributes?  When you debug the client-side code, what value is being used for the id in that one line of code when the problem occurs?  What element on that page has that id value?  Is there more than one element with that id?  Can you update the question to a [mcve] of the relevant client-side code which would demonstrate the problem?

My suggestion for this is also using a update model popup for this kind of condition. This is the best way for handling this.
I suggest you could try below example, it will not modify your table, but show a new popup to modify the selected row.
More details, you could refer to below test example:
Controller:
public class SeizureController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Rqkey = 1,
            Seizures = new List<Seizure>
    {
        new Seizure { Szkey = 1, Category = "Electronics", Item = "Laptop", Qty = 5, Value = 1500.00m },
        new Seizure { Szkey = 2, Category = "Furniture", Item = "Chair", Qty = 10, Value = 300.00m }
    }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    public IActionResult GetEditSeizurePartial(int seizureKey)
    {
        // you should query the seizureaccording to the seizureKey, I just use it for testing 
        var seizure = new Seizure { Szkey = 1, Category = "Electronics", Item = "Laptop", Qty = 5, Value = 1500.00m };
        return PartialView("UpdateSeizure", seizure);
    }

    public IActionResult GetCreateSeizurePartial()
    {
        return PartialView("CreateSeizure");
    }
}
public class Seizure
{
    public int Szkey { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Rqkey { get; set; }
    public List<Seizure> Seizures { get; set; }
}

View:
<div style="background-color:lightgray; width:25%" class="full-width">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:75%; background-color:white" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.Seizures != null)
            {
                int rownum = 0;
                foreach (var sez in Model.Seizures)
                {
                    <tr id="row_@sez.Szkey">
                        <td>@rownum++</td>
                        <td>@sez.Category</td>
                        <td>@sez.Item</td>
                        <td>@sez.Qty</td>
                        <td>@sez.Value</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showEditModal(@sez.Szkey)">Edit</button></td>
                        <td><a asp-action="DeleteSeizure" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove @sez.Item?')" asp-route-id="@sez.Szkey" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="showCreateModal()">Create Record</button>
</div>

<!-- Edit / Create Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="seizureModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="seizureModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="seizureModalLabel">Edit Seizure</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-content">
                <!-- Content loaded dynamically with JavaScript -->
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showEditModal(seizureKey) {
            // Load the Edit partial view into the modal content
            fetch('@Url.Action("GetEditSeizurePartial")?seizureKey=' + seizureKey)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById('modal-body-content').innerHTML = data;
                    $('#seizureModal').modal('show'); // Show the modal
                });
        }

        function showCreateModal() {
            // Load the Create partial view into the modal content
            fetch('@Url.Action("GetCreateSeizurePartial")')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById('modal-body-content').innerHTML = data;
                    $('#seizureModal').modal('show'); // Show the modal
                });
        }
    </script>
}

Partial View:
@model Seizure

<form asp-action="UpdateSeizure" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Szkey" />
    <label>Category:</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Category" class="form-control" />
    <label>Item:</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="Item" class="form-control" />
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Qty" class="form-control" />
    <label>Value:</label>
    <input type="number" asp-for="Value" step="0.01" class="form-control" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
</form>

Result like below:


After working through some issues, I got it working with Brando's advise. Thanks
